# Transitions partially working in react router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

I am trying to animate transitions between routes using react router 4 and CSSTransitionGroup. The appear to work partially - the entering component sometimes animates as desired (but not always), the exiting component disappears with no transition.
Here is the render function that is not behaving as desired:

```
render() { 

    /****************************************For transitions***********/
    // const locationKey = this.props.location.pathname;

    return (
        <CSSTransitionGroup
          key={this.props.location.key}
          transitionName="flipIt"
          transitionAppear={true}
          transitionAppearTimeout={3000}
          transitionEnterTimeout={3000}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={3000}
        >
        <Switch key={this.props.location.pathname} location={this.props.location}>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Welcome} />
            <Route path='/game' render={(props) => (
              <Board {...props} leaders={this.state.leaders} logGameGoes={this.setGameGoes} />
            )} />
            <Route path='/leaderboard' render={(props) => (
              <Leaderboard {...props} leaders={this.state.leaders} syncLeaders={this.syncLeaders} />
            )} />
            <Route path='/winner' render={(props) => (
              <Winner {...props} addLeader={this.addLeader} />
            )} />
            <Route path='/gameover' render={(props) => (
              <Gameover {...props} goes={this.state.currentGameGoes} />
            )} />
          </Switch>
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

The whole app can be seen at this Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vyn7zl2993

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch will render a matched route. Lets say `game` is matched => game will render and the appear transition will run once the component is mounted. Now you go to `winner`, this will unmount `game` and mount the `winner` route. You'll be expecting the `leave` transition to start for `game`, but what will happen is that `game` will be removed from the dom (because of the unmount), so there's nothing to run and the leave transition will not work. The appear transition will start on the `winner` route. So what to do?

You can use a children func (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/children-func) and make the component invisible before unmounting the route. You can't use Switch for this, because it renders routes exclusively.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. I'm not quite sure how to implement it in this instance. As I need to render a single containing element, and I can't use Switch to wrap my routes, would I wrap them in the Animate component, as shown in the docs example you referenced?

Comment: There are probably two things you can do; have two routes active for a short period of time: one appearing and one disappearing or debounce the route change and start the disappear transition. You've got to figure out the code yourself.